# Kubernetes cluster, Docker Container pause and exit in a second

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have setup a kubernetes cluster on 2 ubuntu VMS:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
vm-hps10   Ready     master    33m       v1.10.1
vm-hps11   Ready     <none>    11s       v1.10.1
```

I have a image built locally called user-service so i start a service using the kubectl command:

```
$ kubectl run user-service --image=user-service --port=8080
deployment.apps "user-service" created
```

As soon as i do this i see lot of container spinning up in my worker node, i.e. when i do a `docker ps -a` (On worker) i see

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS               NAMES
53de78d6ea71        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 1 second ago        Exited (0) Less than a second ago                       k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_34
8a0b122e9ca9        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 seconds ago       Exited (0) 1 second ago                                 k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_33
59e940adbff0        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 3 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                                k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_32
c0db383d7db8        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                                k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_31
c4c21c7a8e65        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 5 seconds ago       Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                                k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_30
3dfcd0b39597        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                                k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_29
d6aa24274e7d        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                                k8s_POD_user-service-6d9f9c9977-zdq9x_default_e4b92bf5-43ca-11e8-a03d-00155d0c662c_28
```

I have image available on both master and worker.
I have used the below command for deploying a pod network:

```
sudo kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
sudo kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

Running out of ideas currently, any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S.
Docker version:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8
```

The POD:

```
$kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
user-service-6d9f9c9977-wkqqp   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          10s
```

and

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-vm-hps10                      1/1       Running            0          54m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-vm-hps10            1/1       Running            0          54m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-vm-hps10   1/1       Running            0          55m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-n9vxs          3/3       Running            0          56m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-9nsww              0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-lfw8d              0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   15         54m
kube-system   kube-proxy-4v8vl                   1/1       Running            0          56m
kube-system   kube-proxy-5jpgn                   1/1       Running            0          14m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-vm-hps10            1/1       Running            0          54m
```

When i did kubectl logs -f kube-flannel-ds-4qzg2 -n kube-system kube-flannel i got

```
I0420 03:53:24.646578       1 main.go:353] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I0420 03:53:24.746971       1 vxlan.go:120] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false DirectRouting=false
E0420 03:53:24.747296       1 main.go:280] Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "vm-hps10" pod cidr not assigned
```

Comment: Have you tried that app running on the container? it's look like you containers getting restart also flannel service getting restart as above. have you trace the logs ?

Comment: you mean using standalone docker run command?

Comment: Yes have you try ?

Comment: Yes i did the image is actually a spring boot application which spins up nicely in a standalone docker container.

Comment: If you do `kubectl describe pod kube-flannel-ds-9nsww -n kube-system` and see if gives you hint on why its crashing.

Comment: kubectl describe pod kube-flannel-ds-4qzg2
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-flannel-ds-4qzg2" not found

Comment: ok i got the logs: its Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "vm-hps10" pod cidr not assigned

Comment: Also this error comes as soon as i do a deploy network command, the worked hasnt been joined yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i sorted this out, the problem here was with the kubadm init command i need to specify the CIDR block as a parameter, then when i start a service this works.